# How to use tesseract to detect multiple orientation text in same image?

Tags: tesseract

[image: Multiple text orientation in same image]

In the above image, I am able to detect only the horizontal text. I am using command line tesseract. What parameter options can I use in the Command Line to detect both horizontal and vertical and maybe even 180 or 270 degree text. All in a single image? Is it possible to detect multiple oriented text in the same image automatically

It only detects Hello WORLD but detects some garbage letters for HI WORLD.90 degree  oriented text fails.

Comment: As far as I know you can not do that.

Comment: Any reason why?

Comment: Because it is not supported from the box.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different texts in your original image. I think you can solve the problem in successive steps:

- step 1: **text detection**

  You have to select the 2 areas (rectangles) containing texts. This article shows how to do it with openCV: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/
- step 2: **text alignement/rotation**

  using openCV again, you can rotate the vertical text to become "HI WORLD"
- step 3: **text detection**

  Submit the 2 resulting images to tesseract

See also:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/

Answer (score 0):

For two different text orientation. If your image is fixed ( all images contains very few words with combination of horizontal and vertical text). try to apply following steps:

1. Pass this images to tesseract with psm 11/6 mode you will get horizontal image. pick only those word which has higher confidance.( if something is detected on vertical threshold it's confidance is very low.)
2. Rotate the image by 90 degree and again pass to tesseract with same psm, you will get vertical text with higher accuracy.
3. You can use height /width of boxes for further validation.